# Creating SQLite Database in Cordova and accessing it on android emulator shell

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, android-sqlite

I create a database in my application via

```
window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "mydatabase"});
```

When I want to access this sqlite database via the shell of my android emulator, I call

```
$ sqlite3
$ .database
```

and what I get is:

```
seq  name             file                                                     
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main
```

means, no database found.
What do I do wrong?

---

When I do

```
sqlite3 mydatabase
select * from mytable
```

I get

```
Error: unable to open database "mydatabase": unable to open database file
```

When I do

```
 .open mydatabase
```

I get

```
Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "open". Enter ".help" for help
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sqlite
SQLite version 3.8.6 2014-08-15 11:46:33
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite>
```

You did not tell the `sqlite3` tool *which* database file to use.